# Trouble Creating and Executing an Intel SGX Enclave

Tags: visual-studio, sgx

I'm very new to SGX and wanted to start with something simple. Fortunately, I found [this very basic tutorial](http://ayeks.de/2016/01/Create-and-Execute-an-Intel-SGX-Enclave/). Unfortunately, as simple as it is, I can't get it to work. The code executes, but there are errors in the output.

```
[sgx_create_enclavew ..\urts\win\urts.cpp:195] Couldn't open file with CreateFile() 

error 0x200f, failed to create enclave.

Buffertests:
Buffer before change: Hello World!
Buffer after change: Hello World!

Stringtests:
Returned Secret:
Saved Secret: My secret string
Load Secret:

Integertests:
secretIntValue first load: 0
saved a 1337 to the enclave.
secretIntValue second load after 1337 was saved: 0

error, failed to destroy enclave.
```

[image of output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vmm5z.png)

the tutorial says:

> If you get the error SGX couldn't find the enclave file. The solution is to move the enclave_test_save.signed.dll into the same folder where the app_test_save.exe is located.

which I've tried, but it didn't solve the problem.

when I try to create the enclave using:

```
    sgx_create_enclave(ENCLAVE_FILE, SGX_DEBUG_FLAG, &token, &updated, &eid, NULL);
```

it returns: `SGX_ERROR_ENCLAVE_FILE_ACCESS`

could the problem be a result of using a different version of Visual Studio? (The tutorial uses VS 2012, while I'm using VS 2015)

Answer (score 1):

Did you run the application through command prompt or from IDE?
If you are using IDE, You need to change the debugging properties to **$(OutDir) from $(ProjecttDir) under Project Properties->Configuration Properties->Debugging->Working Directory.(Both Enclave and Application) Select the Intel(R) SGX Debugger**.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I had the same error although under a different setting (Ubuntu, eclipse) so I am not sure to what extent this will help.

Before `initialize_enclave()` is called (which in turn calls `sgx_create_enclave()`), a `chdir(absolutePath)` command needs to be executed, where `absolutePath` needs to be the absolute path to where your executable is.

My error was due to a wrong path I used.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I solved it. turns out I had to place enclave_test_save.signed.dll in the root folder with the .edl file and not with the .exe file.